How to sum multiple tuples in python
I want to calculate the sum of the first n natural numbers and squares.
I have the following, which carries out a single loop and generates the required values
(i, i**2) for i in range(1, n+1), so now I'd like to sum all the is and i**2s.
In numpy I could do sum(np.array([(i, i**2) for i in range(1, n+1)])) as this carries out the sum along the "columns" of the array - what would be the equivalent method without numpy?
I was thinking some sort of useage of map or reduce, but I'm not exactly sure how

A for loop without materializing any arrays or lists would be a perfectly fine solution, in fact, better. Or even better would be to use an analytic solution, for the first n integers its just (n*(n+1)) // 2, for the first n squares it is (n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)) // 6.

Also note, you aren't leveraging numpy effectively here. If you were going to use numpy, something like np.arange(n, n+1).sum(), (np.arange(n, n +1)**2).sum() would make more sense

Another numpy solution: (np.arange(1, n+1)[...,None]**np.array([1,2])).sum(axis=0)

Just use a simple for loop:
result = [0, 0]
for i in range(1, n+1):
    result[0] += i
    result[1] += i**2

Or use two calls to sum()
result = (sum(range(1, n+1)), sum(i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)))


yeah, thanks. I wondered if there was a way to do it with just one loop like your first suggestion, but in one line/with one list comprehension like your second suggestion

[ sum(l) for l in zip(*((i, i**2) for i in range(1, n+1))) ]

Don't actually code this way, as it's unmaintainable, but do remember the zip(*x) construct as a way to transpose nested iterables.

One solution is to use reduce() with your own function to define what "sum" or "combination" means.
With reduce plus a lambda expression:
reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]), ((i, i**2) for i in range(1,n+1)))

I don't think this is particularly elegant code, and it's certainly less readable than the multi-line implementations, but it is a one liner with one comprehension, as you said you're looking for.
Required import: from functools import reduce
